# ggplot2 of categorical data - grayscale/BW theme for enhanced readability

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line graph by group in `R` using `ggplot2` as follows. It is intended for a grayscale print.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Summarise data
mry <- do.call(rbind, by(movies, round(movies$rating), function(df) {
  nums <- tapply(df$length, df$year, length)
  data.frame(rating=round(df$rating[1]), year = as.numeric(names(nums)), number=as.vector(nums))
}))

p <- ggplot(mry, aes(x=year, y=number, colour=factor(rating)))
p + geom_line() + scale_color_grey() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

However the clarity is lacking in the resulting plot as there are 10 groups involved. How to adjust the colors/pch/line style in ggplot2 for better readability in such a case where large number of groups are involved?

Comment: I think it really depends on the message you want to convey with your plot. 10 groups are hard to distinguish in color, let alone in greyscale. Linetype by group can be done but doesn't make it more distinguishable. Is there any particular group you want to show?

Comment: @Heroka I want to show the trend of all the groups over the years. Looking for a better way to plot it.

Comment: Maybe make it into three categories? High, medium and low?

Comment: Or if you really need 10 categories in a greyscale plot you could use `geom_area`; the colours are more easily distinguished when they have larger surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to use facets, like this:

```
ggplot(mry, aes(x=year, y=number))+
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid(rating~.)
```

[image]

Obviously this would be better in portrait mode, but even at this minuscule scale you can tell that ratings of 1,2,3,9, and 10 are extremely rare, and that the most common ratings are 6 and 7 (at least recently). This is much more than you can get from plotting everything on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

An option to improve readability is to use `linetype`  instead of `colour`. But still, 10 groups are probably too many. You could try to add different point shapes with  `geom_point`

```
p <- ggplot(mry, aes(x=year, y=number, linetype =factor(rating)))
p + geom_line() + scale_color_grey() + theme_bw()
```